# Why is Bootstrap 3 column width not exact?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a specific gutter size by doing this:

```
  div[class^="col"]{padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;}

  .row{
    margin-left:-5px; 
    margin-right:-5px;
    border: 0px;
  }
```

Basically, I want gutter to be 10px BUT ONLY BETWEEN columns.

However, row's width is coming out to be 2 px smaller than the container's width. I tried setting border to 0 as above to no avail.

**Edit: I forgot to set padding of container to match gutter. That fixed it.**

However, I am getting width of column as 118.2345 or something when it should have been exact 120. Why is that?

Comment: what is the width of the parent container... that should help determine why the width of each column is a decimal instead of the expected 120px.

Comment: @GPicazo Please see this: http://www.bootply.com/715hqK5cA0 I would expect width of the column to be 89 but it's 88. 88*12+11*12=1188 (and not 1200)..! I want each column to be 89 pixels.

Comment: Ok, that will depend on the resolution of  your browser's viewport. In my case (viewing your bootply), my resolution is > 1200px, so the row width is 1200px and each column width is 100px. Because each column has a red box inside and has a padding of 6px on the left and right, the width of each of my red boxes is 88px, which is correct (100px-2*6px). If you are seeing that the width of your columns is less than 100, then it's because your viewport is < 1200px, so bootstrap scales the width of each column. Check what the width of your .row div is. It should be the width of the column*12.

Comment: @GPicazo I am talking about the width of the red box, sorry. I want the width of the red box to be 89px. I am looking at it on large desktop. See the desired calculation: 89px*12+11*12 = 1200. But what I am getting is 88*12+11*12 right now and I do not want that.

Comment: Actually, you are getting 88*12+12*12. If you want 89*12+11*12, then change the left and right padding of the columns to 5.5px instead of 6px.

Comment: Add or Edit your stylesheet to have this:

@media (min-width: 1200px)
div[class^="col"] {
  padding-left: 5.5px;
  padding-right: 5.5px;
}

Comment: @GPicazo But I want my gutter to be 12 px not 11 px. That's why 11 (number of gutters)*12(width of gutter). Where is that extra 12 px coming from?

Comment: I see what you mean... The reason you are getting odd results is because all the columns have a padding on left and right even the first and last which should only have it on one side... that is where you are missing the other 12px. You could 'cheat' and make your row 112px to account for it by doing:  .row{
   margin-left:-12px; 
 margin-right:-12px;
 border: 0px;
  }

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
.row {margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}
.row div[class^="col"]{padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;}
.row div[class^="col"]:first-child{padding-left:0;}
.row div[class^="col"]:last-child{padding-right:0;}
```

Of course, this assumes that every row you want to display is actually decorated with a .row class. So something like the following will NOT work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
</div>
```

but something like the following will:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

As far as why you are getting decimal width, that is because column widths are percentage based, depending on the total parent width. So check the width of the parent container.